# docker.image.inside in jenkins pipeline error: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I've created a Jenkins pipeline project that should run newman commands inside the newman container. Jenkins is running from a container in Kubernetes. I can pull the image using the docker.pull() command in my pipeline without any issues, but when I want to run commands inside my container using the docker.image("postman/newman").inside {...}  command, I get the following error message:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/michel_newmantest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TestInsideContainer)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh
[michel_newmantest] Running shell script
+ docker pull postman/newman
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from postman/newman
Digest: sha256:8fa374576d55dad7ea5300b04ce4985814a8b57909a357e2b48e35709ac42b03
Status: Image is up to date for postman/newman:latest
[Pipeline] sh
[michel_newmantest] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . postman/newman
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:296)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.version(DockerClient.java:246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:141)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:296)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.version(DockerClient.java:246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:141)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:123)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:15)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor246.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems like docker is missing, but I don't understand why I'd be able to do a docker.image or docker.pull if this was the case. 
Can anyone please give me some advise on what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried to use a different image, but I had the same error message.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        USER_BIN = '/var/jenkins_home/user-bin'
        DOCKER_HOST = 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock'
        DOCKER_CONFIG = '/var/jenkins_home/.docker'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('TestInsideContainer') {
            steps() {
                script {
                    env.PATH = "${tool 'docker'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
                    newmanimage=docker.image("postman/newman")
                    newmanimage.pull()
                    newmanimage.inside() { 
                        sh 'newman --version'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that `inside` relies on commands in the docker image to be present and working as expected.  For instance, the "top" command provided by "busybox" idoes not support what is expected so inside silently fails.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when the agent is started, the PATH is not set correctly. I had a hard time finding the solution. The answer lies not in the pipeline, but setting PATH while launching the Jenkins agent.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/229724088-How-to-set-up-a-Jenkins-agent-to-have-the-same-path-as-the-user-when-connected-via-Remote-Desktop-

This should help.